# Merge rows by type order by count psql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have Elements table :

```
id entity_type likes_count
1     Part        20
2     Ride        10
3     Part        11
4     Profile     12
5     Part        11
6     Part        30
7     Ride        14
8     Part        12
9     Profile     10
10    Part        8
```

So I need sql statement that returns the elements order by Ride,Part,Profile(intercalate) and with likes count desc.

The result will be:

```
id entity_type likes_count
7     Ride        14
6     Part        30
4     Profile     12
2     Ride        10
1     Part        20
9     Profile     10
8     Part        12
3     Part        11
5     Part        11
10    Part        8
```

I have (PostgreSQL) 9.4.1. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
select id,entity_type,likes_count from 
(
SELECT Row_number()OVER (partition BY entity_type ORDER BY likes_count DESC)rn,id,entity_type,likes_count
FROM   elements
) A
ORDER  BY rn,
          CASE entity_type
            WHEN 'Ride' THEN 1
            WHEN 'Part' THEN 2
            ELSE 3
          END
```